# Google SignIn API Sign-Out not working properly

Tags: ios, google-signin

I added `Google SignIn` in `iOS` as described in the 
[Google SignIn for iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start) documentation, tested both with `CocoaPods` and `framework`, the `sign-in` method works but the `sign-out` method is not working.

When I `signed-out` and `sign-in` again, the `state` is `already signed-in` even though I `signed out` , and also called `disconnect` like this:

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut]; // For signOut
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect]; // For disconnecting
```

One more thing, when I `signed out`, the keychain in my phone is removed when I check with:

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].hasAuthInKeychain
```

Anybody know what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Comment: the signOut should sign you out. I suspect it is something in how you "sign in" your users or some other part of your code. do you have signInSilently enabled maybe? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in

Comment: @Sneak I removed signInSliently code as needed.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: @Sneak Nope. It doesn't work also.

Comment: Any solution on this one guys?

Comment: @George Now I'm trying to figure out. Will add a comment if found.